# Creating a function to mix elements from two lists

Tags: haskell

How would I go about writing a function to mix two lists as such:

```
mixLists :: [a] ->  [a] -> [a]

mixLists  [1,2,3] [4,6,8,2] = [1,4,2,6,3,8,2]
```

Answer (score 4):

One simple option would be to write a simple recursive function to process the two lists into one. This function needs 3 possible cases

1. The first list is empty, so we just return the second straightaway as there's no further mixing to be done.

   ```
   mixLists [] ys = ys
   ```
2. The second list could also be empty and as we might expect, in this case we just return the first list, whatever it may be

   ```
   mixLists xs [] = xs
   ```
3. Now if we've made it past those two clauses, we know that neither `xs` nor `ys` are empty, so we only need to explain what to do if both are nonempty

   ```
   mixLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = ?
   ```

   Now we want to create a new list which starts with `x` followed by `y` because we're mixing together two lists, one of which starts with `x` and the other, `y`.

   ```
   mixLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = x : y : ?
   ```

   Now we have to figure out what the rest of this outputted list should be. Our specification presumably says it ought to contain `xs` and `ys` mixed and we can easily calculate that using a recursive call

   ```
   mixLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = x : y : mixLists xs ys
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the limitation that the lists need be the same length, you can solve this with a one liner....

```
mixLists = concat . zipWith ((. return) . (:))
```

It might be an interesting exercise to figure out how this works....  Hint- the function in zipWith can also be written as `\x y -> [x, y]`.

Comment: I thought this would be kind of nice too but it doesn't work: this drops elements after they stop being equal because of `zipWith`.

Comment: @jozefg Oops, you are correct....  I missed that point.  I almost removed my answer, but instead I'll just point out the limitation in the answer, because I am sure others will have the same thought....

Comment: If you're a fan of hideous one liners, how about `fix $ \k xs ys -> maybe ys id $ flip (:) (k ys (drop 1 xs)) \`fmap\` listToMaybe xs`